# Save the processed image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning

I need to work on a huge number of images, around 80GB. I need to preprocess the image so that they are in the right size to be fead into the NN. However, I don't know whats the best way to save these processed image. Currently I just saved it into a list. What kind of file can I export with this list? And how can I do it???

```
from PIL import Image
from zipfile import ZipFile
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random

def main():

    # import data
    labels = []  #list of file names without suffix
    img = []

    with ZipFile('train_8.zip','r') as archive:
        for item in archive.namelist():
          #  labels.append(os.path.splitext(entry.filename)[0])
            if (".jpg" in item or ".JPG" in item):
                with archive.open(item) as file:
                    ima = Image.open(file)
                    ima = ima.resize((928,928))
                    randnum = random.randint(227,701)
                    box = (randnum-113,randnum-113,randnum+114,randnum+114)
                    region = ima.crop(box)
                    img.append(np.asarray(ima.crop(box)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could export your data as a json file

```
from PIL import Image
from zipfile import ZipFile
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import json

def main():

    # import data
    labels = []  #list of file names without suffix
    img = []

    with ZipFile('train_8.zip','r') as archive:
        for item in archive.namelist():
            # labels.append(os.path.splitext(entry.filename)[0])
            if (".jpg" in item or ".JPG" in item):
                with archive.open(item) as file:
                    ima = Image.open(file)
                    ima = ima.resize((928,928))
                    randnum = random.randint(227,701)
                    box = (randnum-113,randnum-113,randnum+114,randnum+114)
                    region = ima.crop(box)
                    img.append(np.asarray(ima.crop(box)))

    # save using json
    f=open('file.json','w')
    f.write(json.dumps({"labels":labels,"img":img}))
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To read it use:

```
import json

# read file
f=open('file.json','r')
d=json.loads(f.read())
f.close()

# save to seperate varibles
labels=d["labels"]
img=d["img"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest format for you to use would be .npy file in case you have enough RAM, which is just a numpy array. Convert your list to a numpy array and then just do

```
 np.save(file, array)
```

You can then load this using the simple command of:

```
np.load(file)
```

If you do not have enough RAM you could use h5 format which is designed for use cases like this, albeit a bit harder to use. It simulates a filesystem inside encrypted data and therefore will reduce your filesize by quite a lot and make sequential access easy. How to get started with this in python is shown here: (http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/).

Another common approach is to just store the files as images and use `tf.data` to load the images on the fly. This is only neccessary if your data is too large to be loaded into memory. Then you can use a .json like my preposter to link labels to images.